# The JavaScript runtime exited unexpectedly when parsing CSV from an URL

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, csv-import

I am trying to import a data file from a web link and then parse it so that I can use the information. I think the problem is the big amount of data. Is there any way to avoid this error?

- Variables year and user are only used to filter data from the dataset depending on the URL

```
function importCSV() {
  var year = "2022";
  var user = "mail@mail.es";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("BBDD");
  var csvUrl = "http://erp.gruposupra.es/csv/download/?token=***************************" + year + "&user=" + user;
  Logger.log(csvUrl);
  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getContentText();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent, ";");
  Logger.log(csvData);
}
```

Comment: please state about the error. Share us the error log.

Comment: As additional information, about `I think the problem is the big amount of data.`, can I ask you about the size? And, in your situation, for example, when Sheets API is used, the same issue will occur? The sample script can be seen at https://stackoverflow.com/q/69592318 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/70536828